# Adding raster layer to map in ArcGIS Pro project using ArcPy not working?

Tags: arcpy, raster, layers, arcgis-pro

I have a raster dataset in a geodatabase and I would like to add it to my map using arcpy. I have tried with the following lines of code but it doesn't work (no error thrown):

```
raster_data = r'D:\ArcGIS_Pro_Projects\Optimity_Alf\Optimity_Viewsheds.gdb\Accelerator_Viewshed_AGL_raster'
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(r'D:\ArcGIS_Pro_Projects\Optimity_Alf\Optimity_Alf.aprx')
map = aprx.listMaps('Optimity Map')[0]
map.addDataFromPath(raster_data)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing in your question to describe what made you conclude that the raster layer had not been added.

I suspect that it was, and that the reason you do not see it in that map of that project after running the code is that you have not included the following at the end to save it.

```
aprx.save()
del aprx
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to verify if the layer is in the aprx:

1. List the maps
2. List the layers
3. Save a copy in a new aprx path